# A method in a class meant to create a shape, doesn't do so

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I made a class that creates a blank JFrame.

Then I created another class, which I added as an instance to the JFrame.

This class has a method, `MakeRect`, that is supposed to make a rectangle on the panel.
I know you could do this by simply adding `g.fillRect(120,120,120,120)` to `paintComponent()`, without another method.
But I'm curious to know why calling another method to do the job doesn't work.
It gives me 'NullPointerException'. Thanks for the help

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    Graphics g;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        makeRect();

    }

    public void makeRect(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(120,120,120,120);
    }

}
```

EDIT: Thanks, I got my answer and it works. Added the `Graphics g` arguement to `makeRect()`.

Is it possible to calls `makeRect()` from a different class?

Comment: I think this basic problem has cropped up ..3(?) times today.  Do you folks actually try looking through some of the other questions before asking?  Pass the `Graphics` instance in the method call.  `makeRect(g);` as opposed to trying to ***store*** something that is entirely transient..

Comment: I tried, nothing helped. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Pass `g` by function argument. You have class member `g` interferring.

Comment: I answered the expanded question this time, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is pass the reference to the Graphics object into makeRect, at the moment you are referring to a member variable that you never initialize.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    makeRect(g);

}

public void makeRect(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(120,120,120,120);
}
```

If you want to be able to modify the drawing from another object, you can't directly draw the rectangle as that only happens in paintComponent. Instead what you do is:

```
int x, y, width, height;

public void setRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
   this.x = x; // Save the dimensions of the rectangle
   this.y = y;
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;

   repaint();  //Tell swing this class needs redrawing
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    makeRect(g);

}

public void makeRect(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(x,y,width,height); // Use the saved parameters to draw with
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Is this the standard way to do things when you want to edit graphic content in a class from a different class? Or are there ways that are more common?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing, but yes. Essentially you tell the class what state it is in - and it then handles the drawing of that. For example with a checkbox you don't say "draw an x" you say "be checked" and it then knows to draw an x.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `g` in your `makeRect` is going to be `null`

You should avoid maintaining a reference to any graphics context you did not create yourself.

Instead, allow `makeRect` to accept a reference to `Graphics`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    makeRect(g);

}

public void makeRect(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(120,120,120,120);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Is it possible to call makeRect(Graphics g) from a different class?

Comment: So,long as you have a valid reference to the class you are trying to call, yes. There a lots of examples on SO

Comment: This is where I get stuck. If I want to activate makeRect() from the Main class, where the instance of DrawingPanel is created. What line of code should I write? Tried different things, none worked.